# How to write a Python regular expression for split string in this way

Tags: python, string

I have a string with the following format:

```
CA 'xxxxxx'
string
string
string
string
CA 'xxxxxx'
string
string
string
string
CA 'xxxxx'
string
string
string
string
```

It's basically a sting that in between each paragraph the word CA and then 'xxxxx' where each x could represent a number of a letter. (It's not x!)

For example:

```
CA 'mmaa22'
```

How can I write a regular expression so split the string by CA 'xxxxxx'?
Note: Each paragraph between the CA 'xxxxxx' doesn't have the same number of lines. It depends.

Thanks you

Comment: Does the string have a fixed length (the one after CA)?

Comment: @yxor Nope, it doesn't have a fixed length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex to split by `r"CA '\w*'"`.

```
import re

re.split(r"CA '\w*'", lines)
# where lines is your input string
```

If your input `lines` starts/ends with `CA 'xxxx'`, you will get an empty string with the above code which you can filter out by:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x != '', re.split(r"CA '\w*'", lines)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves your issue.

```
import re

toSplit = """CA 'xxxxxx'
string
string
string
string
CA 'xxxxxx'
string
string
string
string
CA 'xxxxx'
string
string
string
string
"""
pattern = r"CA.*'"

print(re.split(pattern, toSplit))
```

Comment: Meant to upvote, yours deals with the situation where you get empty strings while mine doesn't.

Comment: Haha. I know it happens. :P